# boot2docker mysql privileges

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm using boot2docker on mac osx 10.9. I have an image with mysql 5.1 installed.

I grant my user with `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` like following:

```
Host: 192.168.59.103
User: root
Password: *81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B
Select_priv: Y
Insert_priv: Y
...
Trigger_priv: Y
ssl_type: 
ssl_cipher: 
x509_issuer: 
x509_subject: 
max_questions: 0
max_updates: 0
max_connections: 0
max_user_connections: 0
```

Where `192.168.59.103` is `host-only adapter` ip of boot2docker vm (result of `boot2docker ip`).

but when I try

```
$ mysql -uroot -proot -h192.168.59.103 -P3306
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '192.168.59.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Moreover if I change `192.168.59.103` to `%` its work but I don't want to open to all IPs.

May docker and port forwarding change something?

Comment: Be careful posting hashes of passwords in public forums.  Although it doesn't make any difference in this case, if you had chosen a secret password, posting the hash would allow brute-force cracking to begin.  MySQL hashes are not stretched which makes them relatively quick to crack if the password choice is poor.

Comment: Yeah you true but actually is a fake password, the hash represent "root" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to not be allowing that IP address to connect. If you change host to 192.168.59.% it should allow any host in that range (192.168.59.0/24) to connect.

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.59.%'
    IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'blah'
    WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: Lol you true. I didn't see that error says 59.3 and not 59.103... My bad. I think 59.3 is the interne boot2docker ip.